# How to set Jackson's deserialization strategy for Collections to obtain a collection of an Immutable Type

Tags: java, json, jackson, deserialization, guava

Here is an example of java class. I need all the fields to be immutable after deserialization.

It can be done if I set the field type to `ImmutableMap` explicitly. But can I instruct Jackson to deserialize it into an `ImmutableMap` neither changing the field type `Map` nor add annotation like `@JsonDeserialize`  ?

```
public class AdCategoryConfigImmute {
    
    private ImmutableMap<String, List<Integer>> sceneMap; // type is immutable explicitly
    
    private Map<String, List<Integer>> trMap;
}
```

Comment: This solution worked for me.    `SimpleModule simpleModule = new SimpleModule().addDeserializer(Map.class, new ImmutableMapDeserializer());
        objectMapper.registerModules( simpleModule);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to specify the subtype for a particular field needs to be deserialized, you can make use of the [`@JsonDeserialize`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.4/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/annotation/JsonDeserialize.html) annotation. Required type needs to be provided through its `as` property.

```
public class AdCategoryConfigImmute {
    @JsonDeserialize(as = ImmutableMap.class)
    private Map<String, List<Integer>> sceneMap;
    
    // getter, setters
}
```

But since here we need an `ImmutableMap` (or its subtype) from Guava library, you need to register Jackson's `GuavaModule` (link to the [Maven repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype/jackson-datatype-guava)), otherwise deserialization would fail.

*Example:*

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String json = """
        {
            "sceneMap" : {
                "foo" : [1, 2, 3]
            }
        }
        """;

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.registerModule(new GuavaModule());

    AdCategoryConfigImmute pojo = mapper.readValue(json, AdCategoryConfigImmute.class);

    System.out.println(pojo.getSceneMap().getClass());
}
```

*Output:*

```
class com.google.common.collect.SingletonImmutableBiMap
```

***Note:** if you're using Spring Boot, it would register the GuavaModule for you while configuring `ObjectMapper` at the application start up (no need to register the module it manually, you only need to add a dependency).*

Comment: Thanks for your answer , can i make this option `@JsonDeserialize(as = ImmutableMap.class)` by default ?

Comment: Thanks for help , but the key point of this question is how to set deserialization of collection type to Immutable implicitly ..